# Swift template library

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, sequence

Could somebody describe how this is possible:

There is following in swift template library:

```
protocol Collection : Sequence {
     subscript (i: Self.IndexType) -> Self.GeneratorType.Element { get }
}
```

And this is ok.

But if you write:

```
protocol Test : Sequence {
     subscript (i: Self.IndexType) -> Self.GeneratorType.Element { get }
}
```

There is compile error:

'IndexType' is not a member type of 'Self'

I can fix this error by following:

```
protocol Test : Sequence {
     typealias IndexType
     subscript (i: Self.IndexType) -> Self.GeneratorType.Element { get }
}
```

But how is work first?

Answer (score 2):

When you see something from the template library, you're not seeing the original source, you're seeing a decompiled version of something that looks a lot like the original source.  That means that sometimes it's missing pieces and/or won't compile for some other reason.

I'd hope that Apple would eventually fix it so that the typealias in this case would be displayed as well, but wouldn't bet on it.

You might increase the odds by filing a bug report at http://bugreport.apple.com